# Not recognizing all elements in list

Tags: list, indexing

I'm trying to read every 10th line in a text file, adding certain parts of the line to lists, and ignore the rest. Each line in my .txt file is a comma-delimited list of 29 elements, and I'm using `line.strip(',')` to separate each line into a list, called `line_list`.

```
for line in current_file:
    if line.startswith('#'):
        pass
    for linenum, line in enumerate(current_file):
        if linenum % 10 == 0:
            line_list = line.split(",")
            time_list.append(line_list[0])
            values.append(line_list[4])
        else:
            pass
```

However, python doesn't seem to be recognizing all the elements in the list. When I print `len(line_list)` it returns the value 29, but doesn't recognize any index larger than 0. So the line `time_list.append(line_list[0])` works but I get an index out of range error for `values.append(line_list[4])`

Printing `line_list[0]` works for all lines and when I print `line_list` I get the entire list of 29 comma separated values.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Thanks to a commenter I removed the double iteration, so the updated code is

```
for linenum, line in enumerate(current_file):
    if line.startswith('#'):
         pass
    if linenum % 10 == 0:
         line_list = line.split(",")
         time_list.append(line_list[0])
         values.append(line_list[4])
    else:
         pass
```

I'm still getting an index out of range error though, for `line_list[4]`

Comment: Why do you iterate twice on the file ? Once normal and once with enulerate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **one** `for` loop — I think you want something like:

```
for linenum, line in enumerate(current_file):
    if line.startswith('#'):
        continue  # Skip it.
    
    if linenum % 10 == 0:
        line_list = line.split(",")
        print(line_list)
        time_list.append(line_list[0])
        values.append(line_list[4])
```

Comment: thank you! I think changing the first `pass` to `continue` did the trick.

Comment: alohamora: The difference between using `pass` and `continue` is that the latter skips everything that follows in the loop and execution advances to the next iteration, whereas `pass` is effectively just a "no-op".

Answer (score 0):

You are using *line* twice a a variable to loop over. This is not a good coding practice and may cause the strange behavior. For example change the second *line* variable to just *l*:

```
for line in current_file:
    if line.startswith('#'):
        pass
    for linenum, l in enumerate(current_file):
        if linenum % 10 == 0:
            line_list = l.split(",")
            print(line_list)
            time_list.append(line_list[0])
            values.append(line_list[4])
        else:
            pass
```